# How to use the count(*) in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to count the number of times a name is produced in a table.  I then want to group the output so that it only shows the name once with the count in the next column.  So far I have the below code but it keeps giving me an error:

```
Select Name, count(*) as NoOfTimes
from CustName
where count(*) >= 3
group by Name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Count()` is known as an **aggregate function**.

To perform operations on the results of aggregate functions, you have to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`, like this:

```
Select Name, count(*) as NoOfTimes
from CustName
group by Name
having count(*) >= 3;
```

Comment: That's awesome.  Thanks SlimsGhost!  Works a treat!